# Why is the click event not triggered when the node covered in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

html:

```
#title {
        position: absolute;
    }
#entity {
        position: relative;
        display: none;
        background: white;
    }
```

---

```
<div id="title" contenteditable=true>aaaaa</div>
<div id="entity">bbbb</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#title').focus(function(){
    console.log('focus');
    $('#entity').show();
})
$('#title').click(function(){
    console.log('click');
})
```

When I click `#title`, result only console 'focus'.  Why does the click event not fire?

Comment: Did you put your javascript inside a `$(document).ready(function() { ... }); `

Comment: @JFit The focus event handler works ;)

Comment: This fiddle replicates issue: http://jsfiddle.net/E4QZ7/1/

Comment: @JasonP Your fiddle was incomplete. Try http://jsfiddle.net/E4QZ7/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/click) to fire both mousedown and mouseup has to fire in the same element, in your case after mousedown the focus event is fired which causes the overlay element to appear, so the mouseup is fired on the `#entity` element thus the click event is not completed

[Click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/click)

> The click event is fired when a pointing device button (usually a
>   mouse button) is pressed and released on a single element.

```
$('#title').on('mouseup mousedown', function (e) {
    console.log(e.type);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7Ph3Q/)

Answer (score 3):

Because click is like a combination of mousedown and mouseup. You are showing `#entity` before you have a chance to mouseup on `#title` thus no click is initiated. Change `.click` to `.mousedown` for wanted effect

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/7en28/)